# How to monitor the total number of SQL Server logins

Tags: sql-server-2005, login, performance-monitoring

We have an SQL Server 2005 that is the backend of a web application.

The application is partly SharePoint and partly web services accessing the database via Entity Framework.

In the performance monitor I am seeing average SQL Logins is ca, 60 per second (max 170), but the average logouts is less than 1.

Where can I see the total number of SQL Server logins? Anyone have an idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the application creates connections during page loads but never terminates them, thus they hang around until they time out/expire.

I would start by setting up a SQL Profiler trace of the SQL Server which will show you logins and logouts.  This will let you see where logins are coming from with unmatched logouts.  The standard profiler template will include logins and logouts, but has some other things included with it that might just be noise for what you're looking for.  You can remove the other events from the trace in order to focus just on the logins/logouts.

Have a look at [**Using SQL Server Profiler**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929%28SQL.90%29.aspx) on MSDN for more detailed info on the Profiler.  It is of high value when troubleshooting SQL Server issues.